# get id from url and passing into form in laravel 5

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

i defined a route as

```
Route::get('roundtables/{name}/tags/store',['as'=>'tags.store','uses'=>'TagController@store','middleware'=>['owner','auth']]);
```

In my view, i have a form in this url

> http://localhost:8000/roundtables/1/tags

```
<div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="well">
            {!! Form::open(['route'=>'tags.store','method'=>'GET']) !!}
            <h2>New Tags</h2>
            {{ Form::label('name','Name') }}
            {{ Form::text('name',null,['class'=>'form-control']) }}

            {{Form::submit('Create New Tag',['class'=>'btn btn-primary btn-block btn-h1-spacing'])}}
        </div>

    </div>
```

My problem is, how to get the id from url which is id '1' and passing into the form when user clicked submit.

My controller

```
public function store(Request $request,$name)
{
    $this->validate($request,array('name'=>'required|max:255'));
    $tag=new Tag;
    $tag->name=$request->name;
    $tag->roundtable_id=$name;
    $tag->save();


    Session::flash('success','New Tag was successfully added');

    return redirect()->route('tags.index');
}
```

Comment: show us your controller code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you're using custom routes for CRUD, avoid using standard RESTful method and route names. Before building the form, you need to pass this variable to the view:

```
public function createTag($name)
{
    ....
    return view('form', compact('name'));
}
```

Define your route as:

```
Route::get('roundtables/{name}/tags/storeTag',['as'=>'tags.storeTag','uses'=>'TagController@storeTag','middleware'=>['owner','auth']]);
```

Then pass variable to from the form:

```
{!! Form::open(['route' => ['tags.storeTag', $name], 'method'=>'GET']) !!}
```

And get it in the controller:

```
public function storeTag(Request $request, $name)
{
    echo $name;
```

Answer (score 2):

You get the *wildcard* value by using `request()` helper method easily.

```
{{request()->route('name')}}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
Request::segment(2)
```

Or pass it from controller:

```
public function index($name)
{
    $tags= Tag::where($name)->first();
    return view('tags.index')->withTags($tags)->with('name', $name);
}
```

Then just pass it into the form:

```
{!! Form::open(['route'=>['tags.store', $name],'method'=>'GET']) !!}
```

Comment: Hi, but my cannot pass the data to controller because there was error "Missing required parameters for [Route: tags.store] [URI: roundtables/{name}/tags/store]. (View: C:\wamp64\www\blog\resources\views\tags\index.blade.php)"

Comment: Oh I see. You're not passing the parameter in the form. Use this in form::open: `'route'=>['tags.store', $name],'method'=>'GET']`

Answer (score 0):

In your TagController

```
public function index($name)
{
    $tags= Tag::where($name)->first();


    // add name parameter to return
    return view('tags.index')->withTags($tags)->withName($name);
}
```

And in your view

```
<div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="well">


            //edit this form tag
            {!! Form::open(['route'=>['tags.store',$name],'method'=>'GET']) !!}

            <h2>New Tags</h2>
            {{ Form::label('name','Name') }}
            {{ Form::text('name',null,['class'=>'form-control']) }}

            {{Form::submit('Create New Tag',['class'=>'btn btn-primary btn-block btn-h1-spacing'])}}
        </div>

    </div>
```

And in your `TagController@store`

```
public function store(Request $request,$name){
         echo $name;
}
```